# yasnippets don't work for javascript-mode

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I have the following code in .emacs:

```
;yasnippet
;;{{{

(load (concat *my-emacs-lib-dir* "plugins/yasnippet/yasnippet"))
(setq yas/snippet-dirs nil)
(yas/initialize)

;; Develop and keep personal snippets under ~/emacs.d/yasnippets
(setq yas/root-directory (concat *my-emacs-lib-dir* "yasnippets"))
(yas/load-directory yas/root-directory)

;;}}}
(add-hook 'javascript-mode-hook (lambda () (yas/minor-mode-on)))
```

I have snippet files in `*my-emacs-lib-dir* "yasnippets/javascript-mode"` and in `*my-emacs-lib-dir* "yasnippets/php-mode"`.

It works well for php-mode and doesn't work for javascript-mode. The settings are identical, the files are ok. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that javascript files are opened in `javascript-mode`? Look to the value of `major-mode` variable (with `C-h v`), and if it's different from `javascript-mode`, then create new directory with name of this mode, and add the file `.yas-parents` inside this directory.  Put `javascript-mode` inside this file, and save...

Comment: It was js-mode. I changed the yasnippets directory name to 'js-mode' and it started to work.

Comment: You can always use parents, if you want to use the same snippets for different modes

Answer (score 2):

The mode name is `js-mode`, and the hook is `js-mode-hook`.